# Elasticsearch query to find documents with number of values of a term equal to a specified number

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have an Elasticsearch index "library" with below mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "book": { 
      "properties": { 
        "title":    { "type": "text", "index": "not_analyzed" }, 
        "author":   { "type": "text", "index": "not_analyzed" }, 
        "price":    { "type": "integer" },  
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want make a query to find all documents(book) where number of author is equal to 3. i.e. I want to make a query which will match

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/library/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            Number of values of term "author" = 3.
        }
    }
}'
```

Is there any way to make such an query without adding an extra term?

[I know the aggregation to find all possible values of a term in search result but wasn't able to convert that aggregation in according to above criteria.]

Answer (score 1):

Can't find a way to get exactly each author with 3 documents.
Aggregation will give you all possible values. But, it also show you the `doc_count` - and there we can find our way:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "authors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author",
        "min_doc_count": 3,
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**min_doc_count** - will filter only buckets with, at least, 3 documents.

**size** - will give you only first 5 documents (remember that, by default, buckets are sorted by 'doc_count' ascending).

Now you can adjust `size` to get exactly those authors with 3 documents.